# User profile fields translated but not showing up on user account modification and registration

Tags: i18n-l10n

I translated my user fields (select list) and they show up fine on:

- Exposed Filters
- In .po files and and translated
- User Display view mode

However, they don't show up translated for users.

Hard to explain...so let me try this way:

A user registers on the site in French, with fr prefixe.

When modifying his account, the drop downs are not shown in French, they are in English. However, even if English selections are selected, the display is indeed translated into French.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you translated the select list options of your (user) field, make sure that you ALSO change the **Format** of that selection list from ***Default*** to ***Default Tanslated***, which you can do via "Manage Display" (located at `/admin/config/people/accounts/display`). Similar to what is explained in [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1101128#comment-6027572) also ...

**Note**: same is true for using such fields within a content type.

Comment: All fields already set up to "Default Translated", the fields display translated, both label and selections. Problem is they do not show on user account creation and options selections in user's own language.

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved.

A. Uninstalled EVERY TMGMT modules, deleted all instances of that module in phpmyadmin

B. Disabled ALL translation related modules

C. Enabled ONLY i18, not entity

Now it works, some entity modules and TMGMT had conflicts with i18 I guess.